# Is Clear-Site-Data HTTP header just a hint?

Tags: node.js, http

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data),

> The Clear-Site-Data header clears browsing data (cookies, storage, cache) associated with the requesting website. It allows web developers to have more control over the data stored locally by a browser for their origins

However, it doesn't seem to clear either cookies, cache, or storage in my browser (*Google Chrome Version 88.0.4324.50*).
Is the header just a hint to the browser?

Node.js

```js
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/html", 
    "Clear-Site-Data": "cookies"
  });
```

Comment: Does that put the `"cookies"` value in double quotes in the actual HTTP response, as shown in the specification?

Comment: I have the same issues - the header is being set but it doesn't actually seem to clear anything.

Comment: Check the browser compatibility table on this page
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data#browser_compatibility